# Run Perl code (with output to file) from Python

Tags: python, subprocess, shlex

I'm trying to run a Perl script from Python. I know that if run the Perl script in terminal and I want the output of the Perl script to be written a file I need to add `> results.txt` after `perl myCode.pl`. This works fine in the terminal, but when I try to do this in Python it doesn't work.

This the code:

```
import shlex
import subprocess

args_str = "perl myCode.pl > results.txt"
args = shlex.split(args_str)
subprocess.call(args)
```

Despite the `> results.txt` it does not output to that file but it does output to the command line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
subprocess.call("perl myCode.pl >results.txt", shell=True)
```

or

```
subprocess.call(["sh", "-c", "perl myCode.pl >results.txt"])
```

or

```
with open('results.txt', 'wb', 0) as file:
    subprocess.call(["perl", "myCode.pl"], stdout=file)
```

The first two invoke a shell to execute the shell command `perl myCode.pl > results.txt`. The last one executes `perl` directly by having `call` do the redirection itself. This is the more reliable solution.

Comment: (This is my first Python code. Feel free to improve.)

Comment: `subprocess.call("perl myCode.pl >results.txt", shell=True)` worked for me, Thanks!

Comment: They all work. The third avoids having spawing a shell to spawn your program.